# Ionic2 Typescript Twilio

Tags: typescript, ionic2, twilio

If anyone has any information/insight on the following, it would be greatly appreciated...

I'm trying to include Twilio in an Ionic2 TypeScript app. It's installed via npm. I can see it's installed successfully in my node_modules, but when I try to import the module it errors.

In my **declarations.d.ts** it's declared as... **declare module 'twilio';**

In my **Page Component** I'm importing it like so... **import * as twilio from 'twilio';**

In other apps, when using something like moment or timezones this is how I imported the required dependency.

However with Twilio, I get the same error regardless of how I try to import/require it.

**Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isTTY' of undefined...**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isTTY' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:28)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 236b50c…:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (AccessToken.js:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 236b50c…:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 236b50c…:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (emergency.ts:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 236b50c…:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (emergency.ts:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 236b50c…:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:174604)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 236b50c…:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (platform-browser-dynamic.es5.js:170)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 236b50c…:19)
```

Ionic Info (output):

```
Cordova CLI: 7.0.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.10.2
```

Once again, any helpful nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading from Twilio version 3.0.0 to 2.11.1 solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The step you missed is installation of type declaration for **Twillo**.

Type declarations of most javascript modules can be found in [DefinitelyTyped Repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).

After doing:

```
npm install twilo --save
```

Do:

```
  npm install @types/twilo --save-dev
```

Check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/twilio).

Then do the import:

```
import * as twilio from 'twilio';
```

You dont have to declare in **declaration.d.ts**

Comment: I believe I had the typing installed and forgot to note it in my post...I ran the command again to make sure and still produces the previously generated error ... TypeError: Cannot read property 'isTTY' of undefined. Someone I'm working with referenced this being tied to Twilio using a deprecated node library. https://github.com/brianc/node-deprecate/blob/master/index.js
and this being the source of the error. But so far we haven't found a fix.

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/354cec620daccfa0ad167ba046651fb5fef69e8a/types/twilio/index.d.ts this is the types declaration.. isnt this the api?

Answer (score 1):

Typings for twilio(@types/twilio version:0.0.9) is not compatible with twilio 3.x API.
That's why downgrading to 2.x solved the problem .

Feature Request :- https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues/250

Related Issue:- https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/18992